Issue with react-virtualized and Vite: "No matching export for import bpfrpt_proptype_WindowScroller"
I am working on a React project (version 16) that is bootstrapped with Vite. I am encountering an issue with the react-virtualized library, specifically with the WindowScroller component. When I try to build or run my project, I get the following error:
Plugin: vite:esbuild
File: /Users/rahulchauhan/Desktop/LeenaAI/leena-ui-components/src/components/DynamicForm/FormField.tsx
✘ [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/react-virtualized/dist/es/WindowScroller/WindowScroller.js" for import "bpfrpt_proptype_WindowScroller"

node_modules/react-virtualized/dist/es/WindowScroller/utils/onScroll.js:74:9:
  74 │ import { bpfrpt_proptype_WindowScroller } from "../WindowScroller.js";
     ╵          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Vite Configuration: Ensured that the react-virtualized package is included in the optimizeDeps section of the Vite configuration.
patch-package: I prefer not to use patch-package to modify node_modules directly.
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import fs from 'fs-extra';
import path from 'path';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import * as packageJson from './package.json';

const fixReactVirtualized = () => {
  return {
    name: 'fix-react-virtualized',
    enforce: 'pre',
    apply: 'build',
    async configResolved() {
      const file = path.resolve('node_modules/react-virtualized/dist/es/WindowScroller/utils/onScroll.js');
      if (await fs.pathExists(file)) {
        let code = await fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8');
        const broken = `import { bpfrpt_proptype_WindowScroller } from "../WindowScroller.js";`;
        if (code.includes(broken)) {
          code = code.replace(broken, '');
          await fs.writeFile(file, code, 'utf-8');
          console.log(`Fixed import in ${file}`);
        }
      }
    },
  };
};

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    }),
    react(),
    svgrPlugin(),
    fixReactVirtualized(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['react-virtualized'],
  },
  build: {
    sourcemap: false,
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'my-component-library',
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
      fileName: format => `index.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [...Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies)],
    },
    watch: config.mode === 'watch' ? {} : undefined,
  },
});


question: How can I resolve the issue with react-virtualized and Vite to avoid the "No matching export" error for bpfrpt_proptype_WindowScroller? Is there a recommended way to handle this problem without directly patching the node_modules directory?
Project Setup:
React Version: 16
Vite Version: Latest
react-virtualized Version: 9.21.2
Bootstrap: Using Vite
Steps to Reproduce:
Installed react-virtualized using npm.
Configured Vite with the necessary plugins.
Attempted to run the project using vite or vite build.
What I Have Tried:
Custom Vite Plugin: Attempted to create a custom Vite plugin to modify the problematic file in react-virtualized to remove the undefined import, but it did not resolve the issue.

In your package.json, put this in the resolutions: "react-virtualized": "git+https://git@github.com/remorses/react-virtualized-fixed-import.git#9.22.3"

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
